# WebSVN install on IIS 6.0

Tags: iis, websvn

I am trying to set up WebSVN on a Windows Server 2003 machine and not having any luck.  I have done the following:

1. Installed FastCGI
2. Installed PHP 5.3.1.0 to c:\PHP
3. Updated php.ini with the following:

   cgi.force_redirect = 0 
   cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1 
   fastcgi.impersonate = 1 
   fastcgi.logging = 0
4. Downloaded and extracted WebSVN 2.3.0 to D:\myWebRoot\websvn
5. Copy distconfig.php to config.php
6. Added the following:

   $config->setSVNCommandPath('c:\Program Files\Subversion\bin');
   $config->setDiffPath('C:\Program Files\FogBugz\accessories');
   $config->addRepository('Documents', 'https://myServer>/myDir/Docs)', null, 'myDocsUser', 'myDocsPassword');

When I browse to URL myServer//websvn, I get the following error:

Error running this command:  "c:\Program Files\Subversion\bin\svn" --version --config-dir /tmp

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be your SVN software version.See WebSVN requeriments :

WebSVN version   SVN version 
 2.3.x          1.4 or higher (usage of "@PEG"-revision)
 2.2.x          1.4 or higher (usage of "@PEG"-revision)
 2.1.0          1.2 or higher (usage of "svn list --xml") 
 <= 2.0          any (?)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You need to grant permission to the cmd.exe in your system32 folder to IUSR_. I'm stuck at the next part, which is getting WebSVN to use the SVN authorization, not anon-access.